# DataGridView New Line is black on black

Tags: winforms, datagridview

When creating a new line in the DataGridView, I get the new line with black background and black text.  However, when I exit editing that cell and edit it again, all colors are ok.  What am I overlooking?

[image: DataGridView with new line (black on black)]

Comment: I think that happens when you have an error in one of the `Paint events`. The `DataGridView` hides the error, but it displays as a black row.

Comment: Maybe you should `return;` or do something else in `CellPainting` or `CellFormatting` if the current row is new. i.e. `if (((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;`. You didn't mention which language.

Comment: Are you painting the rows yourself, or did you set some coloring properties for the rows?